# Best framework for embedding HTML pages in an iphone app?

Tags: iphone, html, frameworks

I am developing an app which has a significant 'reference' section in it.  It's information that is very applicable to being created as a set of HTML pages, linking to each other.

I am wondering if anyone knows of a good framework out there to embed HTML pages within an iphone app, to be able to open a specific page by key and any other niceties.  The best I've seen so far is CMHTMLView on github.

I know I can load HTML pages directly into a UIWebView, I'm looking to see if there's a framework which does a bit of the boilerplate for for me (e.g. checking for existance of files, be able to cache pages by a keyword, any other niceties like being able to index and search pages).  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To display easy to navigate HTML in a mobile, I use http://jquerymobile.com

Comment: Ah I totally forgot about this.  Good suggestion.  Though I was more thinking of a framework to wrap UIWebView inside something that can manage a set of local html files, jump to specific files, etc etc.  I think jquerymobile is a good framework for me to use in actually composing the pages themselves, though, so thanks for the reminder.